# Maven Webapp missing target in TeamCity

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a Maven Webapp configured in TeamCity as a project. My first Build Step is to build the Webapp 
`clean package -P release -Dmaven.test.skip=true`

I have can get resource files after the build in the Artifact paths `%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/src/main/resources/*.* => build_res.zip`

However, I don’t get a target directory, much less, a `.war` file that I can use in the Artificats 
`%teamcity.build.checkoutDir%/ target/*.* => bin`

I don’t get an error and the build is successful. Can anyone shine some light if they have experience this before?

Answer (score 0):

You could be getting error in the log even though TeamCity didn't pick up on it, check the log itself.  Might be permission problems creating the directory.  Make sure the account Teamcity is running under has full permissions to the directory.